# Converting money formatted strings to floats keeping cents, points separation dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe, currency

df numbers on string format:

```
1.160.00
6.76
1.080.029.904.46
1402.0
172.958.956.83
```

How do I to convert them to floats type but keeping the cents?

```
1160.00
6.76
1080029904.46

etc.
```

I've simply tried astype('float') or pd.to_numeric, but it keeps throwing an error:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string " 1.160.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have dataframe:

```py
               col1
0          1.160.00
1              6.76
2  1.080.029.904.46
3            1402.0
4    172.958.956.83
```

Then:

```py
df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(
    lambda x: "".join(x.split(".", maxsplit=x.count(".") - 1))
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            col1
0        1160.00
1           6.76
2  1080029904.46
3         1402.0
4   172958956.83
```